# Stub require statement in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, require, stubbing

I have to maintain a Ruby script, which requires some libs I don't have locally and which won't work in my environment. Nevertheless I want to spec some methods in this script so that I can change them easily.

Is there an option to stub some of the `require` statements in the script I want to test so that it can be loaded by rspec and the spec can be executed within my environment?

Example (`old_script.rb`):

```
require "incompatible_lib"
class Script
  def some_other_stuff
    ...
  end
  def add(a,b)
    a+b
  end
end
```

How can I write a test to check the `add` function without splitting the "old_Script.rb" file and without providing the `incompatible_lib` I don't have?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to the "**Stub require statement in rspec?**" question?  I've got a different use, where I actually want to test that a user-specified file is being `require`d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, I also thought about the option of adding the files, but finally hacked the require itself within the test case:

```
module Kernel
  alias :old_require :require
  def require(path)
    old_require(path) unless LIBS_TO_SKIP.include?(path)
  end
end
```

I know that this is an ugly hack but as this is legacy code executed on a modified ruby compiler I can't easily get these libs running and it's sufficient to let me test my modifications...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of stubbing `require` which is "inherited" from `Kernel`, you could do this:

1. Create a dummy `incompatible_lib.rb` file somewhere that is not in your $LOAD_PATH.  I.e., if this is a Ruby application (not Rails), don't put it in `lib/` nor `spec/`.
2. You can do this a number of ways, but I'll tell you one method: in your spec file which tests `Script`, modify $LOAD_PATH to include the parent directory of your **dummy** `incompatible_lib.rb`.
3. Ordering is very *important* -- next you will include `script.rb` (the file which defines `Script`).

This will get you around the issue and allow you test test the `add` method.

Once you've successfully tested `Script`, I would highly recommend refactoring it so that you don't have to do this technique, which is a hack, IMHO.